# How to validate a multiselect Dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, multi-select

So the situation is this: I'm creating a dropdown box using the jquery.multiselect plugin on a form, but I need to check if there's some value selected, if there isn't one or more values selected I wanna throw a alert or something when some one tries to submit the form.

**The HTML Code**

```
<form id="RNA" name="RNA">
<select size="5" name="sampleMut[]" multiple="multiple" id="sampleMut">

 <option value="41" >41</option>
  <option value="48" >48</option>
  <option value="65" >65</option>
  <option value="102" >102</option>

</select>
</form>
```

**The JavaScript Code**

```
$(function(){
 $("#sampleMut").multiselect(); 
});
```

jQuery version **1.8.3**

jquery.multiselect **1.13**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
         var options = $('#sampleMut > option:selected');
         if(options.length == 0){
             alert('no value selected');
             return false;
         }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aDxu8/1/

Comment: It's doesn't seems to work, but i'm kinda new in javascript :\

Comment: Sorry, I had extra "s" written here: options:selected, need to be option:selected

Comment: Thanks, but in the chrome console appears this message
[prevObject: e.fn.e.init[1], context: #document, selector: "#sampleMut > option:selected"]
context: #document
length: 0
prevObject: e.fn.e.init[1]
selector: "#sampleMut > option:selected"
__proto__: Object[0]

Is there any problem with that?

Comment: No, I was logging that (with console.log()), now I have removed. That's no problem

Comment: Let me ask you something, I'm using ajax to submit this form, it's fine to handle this erro in the error handler?

Comment: I would suggest using validation plugins. Take a look at this: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Answer (score 3):

With this you can get the amount of the selected options.

```
$("#sampleMut option:selected").length;
```